# Espresso test on Android P Preview: Detected problems with API compatibility error

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-9.0-pie

I am using Espresso for instrumentation testing and running them on Android Preview P Emulator.
I have 5 test cases in my test class out of which one test is failing when running the test suite and getting the error below.

> Detected problems with API compatibility

Whereas the failing test case is passing when run individually and not in suite.

Since the dialog gets displayed on the view which says `Detected problems with API compatibility`, I am getting no matching view found in hierarchy exception along with the above mentioned error.

Comment: @ADM i have updated the question to have more details

Comment: I have encountered this as well. Near as I can tell, the problem is with Espresso itself. I wasn't in position to reproduce the problem and file an issue, but I will try to do so if I get it again. Similarly, if you can create a reproducible scenario, file an issue.

Comment: Yep, I just ran into this as well. Nothing in the console either. The link that shows up in the dialog is: https://g.co/dev/appcompat . I believe the "not found" error is because that dialog is blocking your UI.

Answer (score 3):

Changing targetSdkVersion to 28 (previously was 27) made the problem disappear.
I assume for most of the cases this won't be a valid solution but in my case, it allowed to go forward with my project.

Comment: I had this problem in a flutter app and changed it to 28 and it worked.

Comment: Increasing targetSdkVersion to 28 (from 24) worked for me as well.

Answer (score 3):

Referencing to [docs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces):
In Android P, this dialog showing

> Detected problems with API compatibility

Why this dialog is being shown?

Reason:
Your code hit the

> dark greylist

What are dark greylist apis?
Such apis that are not permissible to call by other apps, In my case i was using the startSoftAp method that was dark grey listed. Removing that call vanished the dialog.

How will you find?

> In your logcat -> verbose -> Search("Accessing hidden")
>
> **LOGCAT RESULT**
>
> Accessing hidden method:Landroid/net/wifi/WifiManager:startSoftAp(Landroid/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration;)Z (dark greylist, reflection)